# Dynamically change custom directive attribute value which should change directive content

Tags: angularjs

Basically I have made custom directive to which i pass Url as string then inside the directive controller i'm calling `http.get()` method which creates the content inside this directive. What i want is to be able to change the value of `annotation-url` attribute which in return will change the content inside the directive because the new Url will return different `JSON` object. But it seems the directive is not getting refreshed when i change the `annotationData` from the controller.

HTML

```
<span ng-click="annotatonData = 'data/annotations1.json'">John</span>

 <span ng-click="annotatonData = 'data/annotations2.json'">Marry</span>

    <ng-annotate user-options="user" annotation-url="{{annotatonData}}"></ng-annotate>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('ngAnnotationsController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    //InIt default http get

    $scope.annotatonData = 'data/annotations1.json';

}]);
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('ngAnnotate', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'templates/...',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            annotationUrl: "@"

        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

            $http.get($scope.annotationUrl).then(function (response) {
                $scope.data = response.data;
                 ...
                 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I suggest you change to

```
scope: {
    annotationUrl: "="
}
```

the you can add a watcher to invoke `$http` whenever value is changed

```
$scope.$watch('annotationUrl', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal != oldVal) {
       $http.get(newVal).then(function (response) {
            $scope.data = response.data;
             ...
             ...
    }
}
```

However, if you want to keep `annotationUrl` as it is, you need to use 
`$attr.$observe('annotationUrl', fn)` to catch value changes.

Comment: first if i change it to "=" i will have to pass object not string and remove the http get and play with the passed object. For now i want to play with the string which represents string URL.

Thanks for answer ill check this attr.observe

Comment: change to `=` only requires your template to change `annotation-url="annotatonData"` and you still access `$scope.annotationUrl` inside your directive

Comment: thanks it worked so basically i wrapped everything inside InIt function which i invoke it inside the watch with new value passed